# UITextView reverts animated setFrame: after resigning first responder

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uitextfield, autolayout

I have a UITextView that animates its frame when the keyboard appears like so:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)n {

  double duration = [[[n userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

  [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                        delay:0.3
                      options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                   animations:^{
                     CGRect tfFrame = self.tf.frame;
                     tfFrame.origin.y = tfFrame.origin.y - kbSize.height + 86.f;
                     [self.tf setFrame:tfFrame];
                   }
                   completion:nil
   ];
}
```

There is another UITextField directly below this text field which also animates into place when the keyboard appears. After animation, when the keyboard appears, and I touch the second text field, all of the animations revert back into their original positions.

I've logged the frame's y value through each of the UITextField delegate methods to try to pinpoint where the field is changing, and it seems to change when the first field resigns first responder:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  NSLog(@"did begin: %f", self.tf.frame.origin.y);
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  NSLog(@"did end: %f", self.tf.frame.origin.y);
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  NSLog(@"should end: %f", self.tf.frame.origin.y);
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
  NSLog(@"should return: %f", self.tf.frame.origin.y);
  return YES;
}
```

From the console:

```
2015-03-27 did begin: 521.000000 
2015-03-27 should end: 90.294118
2015-03-27 did end: 521.000000
```

So far I have:

- Tried to modify the autolayout constrains when I adjust the frame
- Tried to completely remove the autolayout constraints

Unfortunately, I don't know where to go from here. I believe this to be an issue with either first responder status on the text fields or autolayout. What should I start checking?

Comment: That's due to auto layout. You should not set any frames when using auto layout. Move the views by modifying their constraints instead.

Comment: @rdelmar you're absolutely right, thanks! Can you make your comment an answer so I can mark it as correct? I'd like to make sure you get credit.